# How to add mouse listener to JOptionPane button?

Tags: java, swing

I want to change appearance of Button on JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog.
I have managed to change Button caption with

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "Text I want");
```

Now, my next goal is to make Button work same as buttons in rest of my app. That is, when hovering mouse over it, it changes background and font color.
On rest of my buttons I added mouse listener like this one:

```
    //setting change color on hover
        private final MouseListener mouseAction = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                JButton rollOver = (JButton)e.getSource();
                if (rollOver.isEnabled()) {
                    rollOver.setBackground(new Color(163, 184, 204));
                    rollOver.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    rollOver.setFont(b);
                }
            };

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                JButton rollOver = (JButton)e.getSource();
                if (rollOver.isEnabled()) {
                    rollOver.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
                    rollOver.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    rollOver.setFont(f);
                }
            };
        };
```

Previously in code I have Font varibles set:

```
    Font f = new Font("System", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    Font b = new Font("System", Font.BOLD, 12);
```

I could make new dialogs from scratch and implent this behaviour but that would be overkill.

Is there some way to access Button on JOptionPane and add mouse listener
to it?

Comment: Instead of `JOptionPane.show...` you can create a JOptionPane and customize it, add a component or such. By a recursive walk through its children you can fetch the right button component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "Text I want");
```

The above will change the text for all "Ok" buttons on all JOptionPanes that you create.

If you want to change the text on an individual button on a specific JOptionPane then
read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Customizing Button Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button).

> Is there some way to access Button on JOptionPane and add mouse listener to it?

When you use the static `showXXX(...)` methods a modal JDialog is created so you don't have access to the dialog or its components until the dialog is closed which is too late.

So instead you need to manually create the `JOptionPane` and add it to a `JDialog`. The basics of doing this can be found by reading the `JOptionPane API` and looking at the section titled `"Direct Use"`.

Once you have created the `JOptionPane` (and before you make the dialog visible) you can then search the option pane for the buttons and add a `MouseListener` to each button. To help you with this you can use the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class. It will do a recursive search of the option pane and return the buttons to you in a `List`. You can then iterate through the `List` and add the `MouseListener`.

The basic code using this helper class would be:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
    "Are you sure you want to exit the application",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

List<JButton> buttons = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JButton.class, optionPane, true);

for (JButton button: buttons)
{
    System.out.println( button.getText() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, this worked for what I need. OK button text is fine to be replaced application-wide, I just set "OK" equivalent word in my language. The part with SwingUtils class and adding MouseListener is what I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the same effect inside all OptionPanels, I think the override BasicOptionPaneUI is a good solution

This is a minimal example

```
public class MyOptionPaneUI extends BasicOptionPaneUI {

    @SuppressWarnings({"MethodOverridesStaticMethodOfSuperclass", "UnusedDeclaration"})
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new MyOptionPaneUI();
    }

    private static final MyMouseListener m = new MyMouseListener();

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.update(g, c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void installListeners() {
       JButton button = (JButton) getButtons()[0];
        button.addMouseListener(m);

        super.installListeners();
    }

    @Override
    protected void uninstallListeners() {
        JButton button = (JButton) getButtons()[0];
        button.removeMouseListener(m);

        super.uninstallListeners();
    }

    public static class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter{
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            JButton rollOver = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if (rollOver.isEnabled()) {
                rollOver.setBackground(new Color(163, 184, 204));
                rollOver.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            JButton rollOver = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if (rollOver.isEnabled()) {
                rollOver.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
                rollOver.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

inside your frame your main class you can add this code for load the class inside the UIDefoult

```
static{
   UIManager.put("OptionPaneUI", MyOptionPaneUI.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

---

Because `getButtons()[0]`, because I see this code inside the `BasicOptionPaneUI`

```
else if (type == JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    defaultOptions = new ButtonFactory[2];
                    defaultOptions[0] = new ButtonFactory(
                        UIManager.getString("OptionPane.okButtonText",l),
                        getMnemonic("OptionPane.okButtonMnemonic", l),
                        (Icon)DefaultLookup.get(optionPane, this,
                                          "OptionPane.okIcon"), minimumWidth);
                    defaultOptions[1] = new ButtonFactory(
                        UIManager.getString("OptionPane.cancelButtonText",l),
                        getMnemonic("OptionPane.cancelButtonMnemonic", l),
                        (Icon)DefaultLookup.get(optionPane, this,
                                          "OptionPane.cancelIcon"), minimumWidth);
                } else {
                    defaultOptions = new ButtonFactory[1];
                    defaultOptions[0] = new ButtonFactory(
                        UIManager.getString("OptionPane.okButtonText",l),
                        getMnemonic("OptionPane.okButtonMnemonic", l),
                        (Icon)DefaultLookup.get(optionPane, this,


                "OptionPane.okIcon"), minimumWidth);
            }
```

inside the method `protected Object[] getButtons()`

---

If you want the effect mouse hover on the button I'm working on [this library](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing) and have the solution for the mouse over.

If you have a possibility to personalize the DefaoultButton inside the library with this constant

```
UIManager.put("Button[Default].background", new Color(163, 184, 204));
UIManager.put("Button[Default].foreground", Color.WHITE);
UIManager.put("Button[Default].mouseHoverColor", new Color(230, 230, 230));
```

ps: this is only information if you need to add the mouse hover inside the you project